# Number of categories of product of fusion rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, fusion-categories

Given two fusion rings $A$, $B$, and let $n_A$, $n_B$ be the number of gauge-inequivalent fusion categories belonging to $A$ and $B$. When one looks at the number of categories $n_{A\otimes B}$ of the tensor product ring $A  \otimes B$ then it turns out that often $n_{A\otimes B} = n_A  n_B$ and sometimes $n_{A\otimes B} < n_An_B$ (e.g. for the direct product of two Fibonacci fusion rings two of the 4 product solutions turn out to be gauge-equivalent).

Is it ever possible that $n_{A\otimes B} > n_A n_B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the fusion ring $A=B=\mathbb N[\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z]$, then $n_a=n_b=2$.  This is because the two categorifications are $\text{Vec}_{\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z}$ and $\text{Vec}_{\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z}^\omega$, where $\omega$ is the unique nontrivial class in $H^3(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z;\mathbb C^\times)$.  The product is $\mathbb N[\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z]\otimes_{\mathbb N}\mathbb N[\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z]\;=\;\mathbb N[(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2]$, which has 8 distinct categorifications up to gauge equivalence, so $n_{A\otimes B}=8$.  This comes from the fact that the Klein four-group has $H^3\big((\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2;\mathbb C^\times\big)\cong(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^3$.

These extra possibilities for the associator/F-symbols can be seen as coming from the Künneth theorem, and are essentially a $\text{Tor}$ term popping up.

---

The above argument works if you are only concerned with gauge equivalence.  More generally, we would like to count the categorifications up to monoidal equivalence, which takes into account the action of the automorphism group on the space of solutions.  Two categorifications are equivalent if they are in the same orbit under this action.

When the $n_A$ count the number of orbits, the above example has in fact $n_{A\otimes B}=4$, so this does not result in a counterexample.  To fix this, we need fusion rings for which the automorphisms act trivially.

Let $A(p):=\mathbb F_p\rtimes\mathbb F_p^\times$ denote the affine general linear group associated to the field $\mathbb F_p$ for $p$ prime.  The nice thing about these groups is that all of their automorphisms are *inner*, and famously inner automorphisms act trivially on group cohomology.  Thus these groups make our situation simpler, because the order of $H^3$ is precisely the number of orbits.

Using the LHS spectral sequence with twisted coefficients, we can compute the cohomology of $A(p)$ from its semidirect factors $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.  Unless I've made a mistake (which is totally possible), for $p>3$, the first few cohomology groups of $A(p)$ are given below.

| n | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $H^n\big(A(p)\text{ ; }\mathbb C^\times\big)$ | $\mathbb C^\times$ | $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$ | $0$ | $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$ | $0$ |

This periodic pattern shown above breaks eventually, and the larger $p$ is, the longer this periodic range is.

From these values, we can use the Künneth theorem to compute that $$H^3\big(A(7)\times A(11)\;;\,\mathbb C^\times\big)\cong \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\,,$$
where the first two summands are $H^3(A(7);\mathbb C^\times)$ and $H^3(A(11);\mathbb C^\times)$ respectively, and the last summand is a $\text{Tor}$ term.

Because $A(7)$ and $A(11)$ only share the prime $2$ in common, we can show that
$$\text{Aut}\big(A(7)\times A(11)\big)\cong\text{Aut}\big(A(7)\big)\times\text{Aut}\big(A(11)\big)\cong\text{Inn}\big(A(7)\big)\times\text{Inn}\big(A(11)\big)\cong\text{Inn}\big(A(7)\times A(11)\big)\,.$$
Thus it follows that the automorphism group of $A(7)\times A(11)$ must act trivially on its cohomology, and so our counting problem reduces to computing the orders of cohomology groups in all three cases.  Finally, if we set $R(p)$ to be the fusion ring $\mathbb N[A(p)]$, we can compute that
$$n_{R(7)\otimes R(11)}\;=\;6\cdot 10\cdot 2\;>\;6\cdot 10\;=\;n_{R(7)}\cdot n_{R(11)}\,.$$

Comment: I edited the question so that it says tensor product. For $\mathbb{N}[\mathbb{Z}/2]\otimes\mathbb{N}[\mathbb{Z}/2]$ I do find that if instead of gauge equivalence, we demand categories to be equivalent up to a combination of gauge and fusion ring automorphism (permutation of the labels of the $F$-symbols via a fusion ring automorphism), then there are only 4 solutions. Do you know whether, up to this more general symmetry, it is possible that $n_{A\otimes B} > n_An_B$?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot about the action of automorphisms on the cohomology.  I will think some more and edit my post if I can find a real counterexample.